# how to create foreign key in sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm newbie android. How to create foreign key in the table? below is my code that create table which are playerTable and attackTable. Please help!

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Create a database table
            String createPlayerTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
                    + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY      autoincrement," + PlayerName + " TEXT not null, "
                    + PlayerAge + " TEXT not null, "+PlayerBorn+" TEXT not null, "+PlayerWeight+" TEXT not null, "+PlayerHeight+" TEXT not null);";
            db.execSQL(createPlayerTable);

            String createAttackTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ATTACK
                    + " (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," + playerAttack + " TEXT not null, "
                    + playerPassing + " TEXT not null);";
            db.execSQL(createAttackTable);
```

Besides that, can autoincrement start from other number such as 1000? I mean autoincrement start from 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on... i want the number start from 1000, 10001, 1002... is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the foreign key after the column definition, with keyword FOREIGN KEY:

For example to create a foreign key to column playerPassing of `table TABLE_ATTACK`  that says that `playerPassing` is referencing table `TABLE_NAME` and it's `column _id`, you put something like the following code after

```
"TEXT not null" :
+"FOREIGN KEY("+ playerPassing +") REFERENCES "+ TABLE_NAME + "(_id)"
```

Comment: To start autoincrement from a certain value, you can insert the first row with the primary id having a value from which you want to start incrementing, for example:
    insert into TABLE_NAME (_id, some_column) values (1000, some_value);

Comment: Sorry, i can't get what you mean. Can you provide the more example?

Comment: When you insert rows in your table, just insert the first with defined id, like this: String insertFirstRowIntoPlayerTable = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME
                + " (_id," + PlayerName + ", "+ PlayerAge + ", "+PlayerBorn+" , "+PlayerWeight+" , "+PlayerHeight+" ) values (1000, some_value1,some_value2,some_value3,some_value4,some_value5)";

Comment: you save me, friend! thank you very much! BTW, "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id," + PlayerName + ", "+ PlayerAge + ", "+PlayerBorn+" , "+PlayerWeight+" , "+PlayerHeight+" ) values (1000, some_value1,some_value2,some_value3,some_value4,some_value5)"; 

the some_value1 refer to what?

because i have seen somebody declare like:
"insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id," + PlayerName + ", "+ PlayerAge + ", "+PlayerBorn+" , "+PlayerWeight+" , "+PlayerHeight+" ) values (?,?,?,?,?)"; 

can this work?